# Coloured tables in ACM Master Article Template

Tags: tables, color, acm

I'm currently writing a text in the new [ACM Master Article Template](https://www.acm.org/publications/proceedings-template). I have a colour-coded table looking like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 & A & B & C & D \\ \hline
E & \cellcolor[HTML]{67FD9A}1 & \cellcolor[HTML]{67FD9A}2 & \cellcolor[HTML]{67FD9A}3 & \cellcolor[HTML]{67FD9A}4 \\ \hline
F & \cellcolor[HTML]{67FD9A}5 & \cellcolor[HTML]{FD6864}6 & \cellcolor[HTML]{FD6864}7 & \cellcolor[HTML]{FFCCC9}8 \\ \hline
G & \cellcolor[HTML]{67FD9A}9 & \cellcolor[HTML]{F8FF00}10 & \cellcolor[HTML]{F8FF00}11 & \cellcolor[HTML]{FCFF2F}12 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I created this example using the [Tables generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/) but unfortunately it makes use of the 'xcolor' package, which I'm not allowed to use with this template. The list of whitelisted packages can be found [here](https://www.acm.org/publications/taps/whitelist-of-latex-packages).

My question is: How can I create a colour-coded table as above using only the whitelisted packages? I would like to be able to specify the colours in HTML format to make use of the colours coming from the [ColorBrewer](http://colorbrewer2.org) tool.

Thank you very much!

Comment: if `xcolor` package are not allowed, means that colored tables are not welcome!. If you persist to have colored tables, try to draw table as image. for example with`matrix` library from package `tikz`.

Comment: I'm not so sure that coloured tables are not welcome. If that were the case, ACM would have stated that somewhere and probably wouldn't allow for the usage of the "color" package. It's true though that they do put an emphasis on careful colour usage for colour-blind people.

Comment: as colortbl is not in the list, don't color tables.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments. I just learned that "the “acmart” document class includes the “booktabs” package — https://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs — for preparing high-quality tables." Maybe it's possible to colour the table using that package. If I encounter any problems doing that, I will just open a new question.

Answer (score 1):

I contacted the ACM Latex support team and learnt that colouring tables is possible by adding the following command right before the "\documentclass" statement:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{table,xcdraw}{xcolor}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `\documentclass[sigconf,dvipsnames]{acmart}`